# Loading remote data with Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Trying to load remote data via Select2, but nothing seems to be firing. The idea here is when a user selects a Brand from the brand dropdown (`brand_id`), we want to fetch all products for that brand and popular the product dropdown (`product_id`).

```
$('#brand_id').on("select2:select", function(e) {
  console.log('fetching products...');
  $('#product_id').select2({
    ajax: {
      type:     "GET",
      url:      "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        brand_id: $('#brand_id').val()
      },
      processResults: function(data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
  });
});
```

So, when I change the brand select, the "fetching products" log gets fired, but the Ajax call never is actually hitting the url I specified. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery-select2, but setting `cache:false` should do the trick

Comment: @japrescott thanks, but unfortunately still getting nothing. It's as if the entire ajax call is just silently being ignored..

Comment: what do you see in your chrome dev tools under network? is the request fired but you never receive it on your server? Be aware that when you have a `GET` call with a `data`, it will be appended to your url -> `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?brand_id=value` and  for the server to receive that, it must be listening on that route!

Comment: Yea, there is no request being fired at all under network. The server is setup to receive that ^ request you mentioned; it's just that no request is being fired whatsoever...

FWIW https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Comment: if you can setup a standalone jsfiddle, I can have a look. One last guess; Make sure you have an element with id `brand_id` and one with id `product_id` or else jquery and select2 won't do anything

Comment: Dude, I think I just discovered the issue. The remote data feature is not designed to work this way. It is designed to actively search as you type, not to load in options in a one-time ajax call. So I need to have a re-think. Thanks for your help.